# Как на чистом CSS реализовать открытие одной вкладки и закрытие другой

Tags: javascript, html, css

На странице есть несколько элементов `details`. Как мне сделать чтобы единовременно мог быть открыт только один из них? Чтобы когда открываешь другой - то открытый закрывается. Я почти уверен что это можно сделать на чистом css не прибегая к js. Там же есть состояние `open`.

Я хочу сделать блок комментариев как на хабре:

```css
ul.comments-list {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.comment {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.comment b a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.comment details summary small {
  color: #548eaa;
}

summary {
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

details > summary:first-of-type {
    list-style-type: none;
}

details summary::-webkit-details-marker {
    display:none; 
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="comments-list">
  <li>
    <div class="comment" id="comment_1">
      <b>автор 1</b>
      <span class="text-muted">
        4.05.18 в 17:07
        <a href="#comment_1" title="Ссылка на комментарий">#</a>
      </span>
      <div>коммент 1</div>
      <details>
        <summary><small>Ответить</small></summary>
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <textarea class="form-control"></textarea>
          </div>
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" value="Отправить">
        </form>
      </details>
    </div>
    <ul class="comments-list">
      <li>
        <div class="comment" id="comment_2">
          <b>
            <a href="https://vk.com/12345">
              <i class="fa fa-vk" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
              автор 2
            </a>
          </b>
          <span class="text-muted">
            4.05.18 в 17:15
            <a href="#comment_2" title="Ссылка на комментарий">#</a>
          </span>
          <div>коммент 2</div>
          <details>
        <summary><small>Ответить</small></summary>
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <textarea class="form-control"></textarea>
          </div>
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" value="Отправить">
        </form>
      </details>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Приведите пример кода

Comment: @vihtor [вот](https://jsfiddle.net/qgzrdp07/6/) (я делаю блок комментариев вроде хабровского)

Comment: Если чистым `css`, то только при помощи `input type="checkbox"`

Comment: @Air что вы имеет ввиду? Мне никакие чекбоксы визуально там не нужны. Можете показать пример?

Comment: А `display - none ` на что? можно просто скрыть

Comment: @Air мне не нужно их скрывать (=_=) Они должны закрыться - убрать псевдокласс `open`.

Comment: Щас покажу.......

Comment: @DarkByte, только свою разметку покажи....

Comment: @Air выше [ссылку](https://jsfiddle.net/qgzrdp07/6/) же давал

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я уверен, что нельзя изменить состояние элемента(`open,checked, disabled` и пр.) при помощи `css`.

```js
$('.comment details').click(function(){
    $(this).parents('.comments-list').find('details').not(this).prop('open', false);
})
```

```css
ul.comments-list {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.comment {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.comment b a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.comment details summary small {
  color: #548eaa;
}

summary {
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

details > summary:first-of-type {
    list-style-type: none;
}

details summary::-webkit-details-marker {
    display:none; 
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="comments-list">
  <li>
    <div class="comment" id="comment_1">
      <b>автор 1</b>
      <span class="text-muted">
        4.05.18 в 17:07
        <a href="#comment_1" title="Ссылка на комментарий">#</a>
      </span>
      <div>коммент 1</div>
      <details>
        <summary><small>Ответить</small></summary>
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <textarea class="form-control"></textarea>
          </div>
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" value="Отправить">
        </form>
      </details>
    </div>
    <ul class="comments-list">
      <li>
        <div class="comment" id="comment_2">
          <b>
            <a href="https://vk.com/12345">
              <i class="fa fa-vk" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
              автор 2
            </a>
          </b>
          <span class="text-muted">
            4.05.18 в 17:15
            <a href="#comment_2" title="Ссылка на комментарий">#</a>
          </span>
          <div>коммент 2</div>
          <details>
        <summary><small>Ответить</small></summary>
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <textarea class="form-control"></textarea>
          </div>
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" value="Отправить">
        </form>
      </details>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Жаль. Кстати элементы не расположены один за другим, так что siblings не поможет, но смысл понятен...

Comment: и не работает с двойной вложенностью и так же не сработает с большей вложеностью

Comment: Вообще я пытался сделать вот так: `$('details:open').prop('open', false);` - не вышло! `Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: open` Что за прикол?

Comment: @Dark Byte, поставил вашу разметку

Comment: @ГеннадийЖуров  а работает с большой вложенностью ?

Comment: @Максим Ленский, вложенностью `<details>` друг в друга?

Comment: @ГеннадийЖуров   у вообще да ... с большой вложеностью  работает

Comment: @ГеннадийЖуров  я имел ввиду про вообще большую вложенность

Answer (score 1):

```css
label {
  margin-top: 5px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.block {
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

input {
  display: none;
}

.block {
  margin-top: 5px;
  color: white;
}

input:checked~.block {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<label for="myid1">
<input id="myid1" class="myclass" type="radio" name="myname" />
  <div class="block">
    block-1
  </div>
  </label>
<label for="myid2">
<input id="myid2" class="myclass" type="radio" name="myname" />
  <div class="block">
    block-2
  </div>
</label>
```

Comment: А где details? Вы не могли бы сделать это в контексте моего кода? Я же приводил ссылку два раза уже.

Comment: Но я бы выбрал на твоем месте вариант `Геннадий Журов`  такое на `js` лучше реализовывать

Comment: Пока что его вариант не работает.